# PostgreSQL. Удалить текст начинающийся с одной строки, но имеющий различия в дальнейшем

Tags: sql, регулярные-выражения, postgresql, replace

В таблице есть колонка с описанием.
Нужно убрать из этого описания последний блок текста.
Этот блок всегда начинается с одной и той же строчки но в дальнейшем имеет различия.

Задача удалить этот блок во всей таблице не затронув текст который идет до него.

Пробовал реплейсом

```
UPDATE
   category
SET
   description = REPLACE (
    description,
    '<h2>Текст с которого начинается блок%',
    ''
   )
where description like '%<h2>Текст с которого начинается блок%'
```

Реплейс не окозазал эффекта, прсле применения запись продолжает находиться.

Пробовал составить регулярное выражение, но sql имеет свой диалект.

Известен метод которым можно выполнить такую операцию, или подходящая регулярка?

Comment: `REGEXP_REPLACE (description, '<h2>Текст с которого начинается блок.*', '')`?

Comment: Приведите однозначные примеры текстов и что в них найти в соответствии с описанием метки [tag:регулярные-выражения]

Answer (score 1):

> Реплейс не окозазал эффекта

И не окажет, так как в строке, по всей видимости, нет знака `%`, `REPLACE` *"заменяет все вхождения в *`string`* подстроки *`from`* подстрокой *`to`*"*. См. [документацию](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/9.5/functions-string).

Используйте `REGEXP_REPLACE`:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE (description, '<h2>Текст с которого начинается блок.*', '')
```

Тут `<h2>Текст с которого начинается блок`  – буквальный текст, а `.*` найдёт ноль и более любых символов.